# RESOLVED : axios repeat in a loop a request but I don't want this | axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, axios

I code a page in react, it interacts with a small API code with express by me and I created a button when I click on it it deletes a message but when I don't click the function is still executed... my code:

```
delete(id){
    for (let i = 0; i<1; i++) {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/messages/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {<button type="submit" onClick={this.delete(messageId)}>suprimmer</button></li>}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: you can use `onClick={() => this.delete(messageId)}`, otherwise your function will run when your JSX is initially returned from`render()`. You also don't need a for loop in your `delete()` method if you're only doing 1 iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => this.delete(messageId)}>suprimmer</button>
```

When you do it as you did in your version, you are actually calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` receives **value** as its `function` to trigger/call/run when user "click" on it. But in your code, you trigger/call/run function `this.delete()` during compile phase (compiler read `Button onClick={this.delete(id)}>Delete Button</button>` and called `this.delete(id)` immediately and use the result of it as onClick's value(delete function return nothing it means `{return undefined}`, so the final result is ` ).

So the result is:

- Everytime the component loaded, it will call delete instantly. And `onClick` value now is `undefined` and it makes `onClick` won't work as expected.

For more details I'll give an example below:

```js
const DeleteButton =({id})=> {
  const delete = (id)=> {
      return api.deleteItem(id)
  }

  return <Button onClick={delete(id)}>Delete Button</button>

}
```

So, when I use the component above:

```
<Container>
  <Content value={item}/>
  <DeleteButton id={item.id}/>
</Container>
```

it will automatically delete the item you've loaded, because while render `DeleteButton` it called `delete(id)` already.

So, how to fix it? - there are many solutions for it, but ultimately it have to give the type of value of `onClick` is `a function`:

#1 I bet noone use this, but I think it is more useful to describe my idea.

```js
const DeleteButton =({id})=> {
  const delete = (id)=> {
      return function() {
       api.deleteItem(id)
      }
  }

  //delete(id) called and it returns an anonymous function that receive `id` and called it when onClick trigger
  return <Button onClick={delete(id)}>Delete Button</button>

}
```

#2

```js
const DeleteButton =({id})=> {
  const delete = (id)=> {
     return  api.deleteItem(id)
  }

  return <Button onClick={(id)=>delete(item.id)}>Delete Button</button>
//or use bind : bind is return a function that wrapped parameter into
  return <Button onClick={delete.bind(id)}>Delete Button</button> 

}
```